# how to increase number on sql server column

Tags: sql, sql-server

hy there i have a record like this

```
name   | phone | emp_pin
-----------------------
anton1 |12345  | null
budi   |12345  | null
santoso|12345  | null
hendri |12345  | null
```

and i have declare variable

```
set @nik_temp = (select [Pin_Number] from [Pin_Number_Seq])
set @total = (select count name from emptable)
```

how do i achieve this

```
name   | phone | emp_pin
-----------------------
anton1 |12345  | 100001
budi   |12345  | 100002
santoso|12345  | 100003
hendri |12345  | 100004
```

i have try using do while but its make the record become duplicate

Comment: emp_pin is a sequence number or zipcode you are trying to pull from different table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Row_Number as below:

```
Select [Name], [Phone], 
   emp_pin = 100000 + Row_Number() over(order by [Name])
from emptable
```

Comment: thanks man thats was help me alot

Answer (score 0):

try to do this

```
create table emptable(
name  varchar(400),
phone int(11),
emp_pin int(16) auto_increment,
PRIMARY KEY (emp_pin)
)


ALTER TABLE emptable AUTO_INCREMENT=100001;
```